# Postgresql - Return empty string on left join instead of null

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have two tables :

Person table

| idPerson (uuid) | name (varchar) | creationDate(date) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | bob | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | sam | 2022-01-02 |

Telephone table

| idTelephone (uuid) | number(varchar) | actif(boolean) | valid(boolean) | idPerson (uuid) | creationDate(date) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34343443 | true | true | 1 | 2022-02-22 |
| 1 | 35676878 | true | false | 1 | 2022-02-15 |
| 2 | 32432 | false | false | 2 | 2022-02-24 |

SQL :

```
select p.idPerson, t.number
from person p
left join telephone t on t.idPerson = p.idPerson and t.actif=true and t.valid =true
```

where t.creationDate >'2022-02-22';

The above query will return only the first row for personId = 1.

Question :
I want the query to return empty String for personId = 2. How can I achieve this please?

Please note that , a person can have multiple telephone numbers but only 1 valid and the remaining will be valid = false.

**Current Result:**

```
1     34343443
```

**Expected Results:**

```
1     34343443
2     ' '
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Column number data type?

Comment: The query will return **both** rows from the person table. If you want a `null`  value for `personid`, then just use `t.idperson` instead in the select list (however you can't return an "empty string" for a column defined as an integer)

Comment: Expected results : Return rows with have valid telephone no. Normally a person can have multiple telephone numbers with only one Valid. However in case the person has only 1 telephone number and it's not valid, I want to return empty string.

Results:

1   , 34343443
2   ,  ' '

Answer (score 1):

you can use case when

```
   select p.idPerson, 
   case when t.number is null then ''' ''' else
   t.number end as nm
    from person p
    left join telephone t on t.idPerson = p.idPerson
     and t.actif=true and t.valid =true
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0980ca83884a8fb50b5dca81be394905)

Comment: Then I will have the two records for Person 1. 

1 34343443 true true 1
1 35676878 true false 1


Normally it should return only line where actif = true and valid = true. In case a person has only one line in telephone and it's not valid, i want to return it as empty string (check my expected results above)

Thanks

Comment: @Alina edited check now

Comment: Since you add the condition on the left join, it’s same as my current results (above)

Comment: @Alina https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0980ca83884a8fb50b5dca81be394905 check fiddle

Comment: I have modified the query by adding a creation date. Can you check now pls ?

Answer (score 1):

Your query *will* return a row for `idperson` number 2, but the `number` will be NULL.

To get an empty string instead, use

```
coalesce(t.number, '')
```